# Track social interaction of shared content

Tags: ios, facebook, google-analytics, social-networking, tracking

Let's say I have an iOS app where users upload videos. They sign in to the app via Facebook (keeping this question simple). Every uploaded video has a Share button. When the user clicks it, the video will be posted on their Facebook timeline as an embedded video.

As the app owner, is it possible to track how many views, likes, comments, average viewing time, geographic location etc. that shared post is generating for this user? I'd like to know which user is popular.

I've done some reading and it looks like Google Analytics (GA) may be what I'm looking for. [Link here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/social). Is this the right tool for my needs?

Once the video has been shared (assuming the URL is custom-crafted that has my Google Analytics Id, Campaign Id etc), how does GA track this data? The Like button is part of the Facebook website. The video is embedded in a container. How does GA communicate with Facebook?

I'd like to track the same when a user shares a link on their Twitter and track the retweets, sharing on Google+ etc. Is this really possible?

Comment: I don’t think you can track plays of an embedded video using GA – when the user plays an embedded video, they do not actually visit your page that the video is on.